# Deep Linking with Query Parameters

Tags: angular

I have got a search page with a few filters whose model is defined as below:

```
interface MyFilter {
    pageNumber: number;
    isSpecial: boolean;
    date?: DateTime;
    text?: string;
}
```

Each particular search on this page can be shared with a URL that has all these filters, similar to the below:

```
https://www.example.com/search?pageNumber=1&isSpecial=false
```

And I use the below code to put the current filters into the URL as query parameters for deep linking:

```
this.router.navigate([], {
    relativeTo: this.activatedRoute,
    queryParams: myFilter,
    replaceUrl: true
});
```

When I try to get the query params with the below code

```
this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
    ...
});
```

All values in `params` are strings whereas `pageNumber` should have been a number and `isSpecial` a boolean. So I am wondering if there is a way to get the correct data type from `params`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query params are `strings` and they need to be converted to desired types after fetching the values.

I passed queryParam value with a number value:

```js
this.router.navigate([],
{
    relativeTo: this.route,
    queryParams: {myFilter: 1}
});
```

And when I retrieve the value:

```js
this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
    let myFilter = params['myFilter'];
    console.log(typeof myFilter) // The type will be string here
   // You need to use any string to number approach to convert them manually
   let converted = +myFilter;
   console.log(converted) // number
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If I am not mistaken, all things passed in the url will be treated as strings, it is on you to properly parse them out to their correct types.